# Program doesn't end after user types in "q" for quit outside the function - Python while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, user-input

I want the user to add new items to the list. When user enters "q", I want the program to quit and then use this list as an input for another function.
But I can't break out of the loop as "Q" is added to the list:

```
base = ["item1", "item2"]

def add_item(item, base=base):
    item=item.upper()
    base.append(item)
    return base

while True:
    user_input = add_item(input("Add an item or enter q to finish: "))
    if user_input == "Q":
      break

    else:
       print(f"New item added: {user_input}")
print("Added")
```

Also, how can I later use the final output (final list) as input for another function?
I would like to check if the item is already in the list, then do something with this item.
I have a general idea that maybe I should use "global" like this:

```
def check(item):
  global base
  if item in base:
    print("in the list")
  else:
    print("not here")
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: `user_input` holds the return value of `add_item`. `add_item` never returns the string `"Q"`. You should check the user input _before_ you call `add_item`.

Comment: Also in your code you are checking for capital Q and in your question you say `When user enters "q"` (underscore q). Underscore q will never end your program.

Comment: But I'm also changing it to uppercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because user_input is the return value of your function not the actual input of the program which user typed!

```
in = input("Add an item or enter q to finish: ")
if in == "Q":
      break
else:
      user_input = add_item()
```